# Pushing Rails App to Heroku - "fatal: Could not parse object"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am a Noob trying to push my first app from onemonthrails.com up to heroku. I have been trying to solve this issue on stackoverflow and other sites. I cannot seem to come up with an answer. I tried deleting the gem-file then recreating before I pushed it up, diddn't work.

Also, I started with a heroku app and then I deleted it halfway between, but I think I got that issue solved with the heroku documentation.

**This is what's happening now:**

```
Johns-MacBook-Air:pinteresting johnsalzarulo$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 815, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (750/750), done.
Writing objects: 100% (815/815), 19.55 MiB | 854.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 815 (delta 388), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git
       fatal: Could not parse object '0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'.
       Retrying git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964 due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964` in directory /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-0e88056ac5d5 has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
       fatal: Could not parse object '0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'.
       Retrying git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964 due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964` in directory /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-0e88056ac5d5 has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
       fatal: Could not parse object '0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'.
       Git error: command `git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964`
       in directory
       /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-0e88056ac5d5
       has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
       '/tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git
       fatal: Could not parse object '0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'.
       Retrying git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964 due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964` in directory /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-0e88056ac5d5 has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
       fatal: Could not parse object '0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'.
       Retrying git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964 due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964` in directory /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-0e88056ac5d5 has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
       fatal: Could not parse object '0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964'.
       Git error: command `git reset --hard 0e88056ac5d58fb0bbd23d3fe929eac01712d964`
       in directory
       /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/bootstrap-sass-0e88056ac5d5
       has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
       '/tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:johnsalzarulololz.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:johnsalzarulololz.git'
Johns-MacBook-Air:pinteresting johnsalzarulo$
```

**Here is my Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' # sass-rails needs to be higher than 3.2
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
gem 'devise', '~>3.1.0.rc2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0' #Finally got this installed!
gem 'heroku', '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~>0.2.0'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'will_paginate', '~>3.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.16.1'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: try `git rm -rf /tmp/build_f4678a3f-b875-4162-a8aa-926fcff3a580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/bootstrap-sass-33efd1d8ffb6176fdb805029a30f02a6edfbae2e` then commit and push again

Comment: Looks like you've included `git reset --hard` somewhere - that's what you'll have to look at to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being related to my Bootstrap gem.

This gem:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
```

Actually needed to be:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.0'
```

I fixed this, ran bundle install and my issue was solved. I could push it just fine.

Comment: How did you find that out?

Comment: A lot of trail and error... Not sure where I actually found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

update Gemfile.lock

- rm Gemfile.lock
- bundle install
- git commit -am 'fixing version cache dependencies'
- git push heroku master